# Reveal JS Remove the fixed aspect ratio for a specific slide

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe, reveal.js

I am using Reveal JS to create a presentation for an Application I have build.

I want to demo the application from within the presentation by embedding it in an iframe.

But I want that iframe to appear full screen.

Tradionally , all slides in revel js  have a aspect ratio on all sides which is coded in reveal.js file.

.
.
.

```
( this, function() {

'use strict';

var Reveal;

var SLIDES_SELECTOR = '.slides section',
    HORIZONTAL_SLIDES_SELECTOR = '.slides>section',
    VERTICAL_SLIDES_SELECTOR = '.slides>section.present>section',
    HOME_SLIDE_SELECTOR = '.slides>section:first-of-type',

    // Configuration defaults, can be overridden at initialization time
    config = {

        // The "normal" size of the presentation, aspect ratio will be preserved
        // when the presentation is scaled to fit different resolutions
        width: 960,
        height: 700,
```

.
.
.

Is there any way to remove this ratio for a specific
    <section></section> 
?

EDIT : I have already tried adding a new CSS Class with padding and margin set to 0 and height and width to desired size .But thats not working.

Comment: You could just set `padding` to   `0`? `section{padding:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class style :

```
<section class="nopad">
    What you want to show
</section>
```

css :

```
section.nopad{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Upon further R&D , found issue was due to js not css. Please refer updated question.

Comment: Maybe you can create a js function that add or remove nopad class style...

Or add padding & margin 0 to style directly